# How to concatenate several (more than 2) 2D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, concatenation

I have the following 2 sets of arrays and I just want to concatenate them in the following order:

In this first case I just want to take the first two elements of a and all of b.

**INPUTS**

```
a = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]]
b = [[2,2],[2,2]]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
c = [[1,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,2]]
```

And also for the second case

**INPUTS**

```
a = [1,1]
b = [2,2]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
c = [1,1,2,2]
```

I also accept numpy solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `+` operator

```
>>> a = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> b = [[2,2],[2,2]]
>>> a + b
[[1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2]]

>>> a = [1,1]
>>> b = [2,2]
>>> a + b
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Since you mentioned numpy as well, you can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
>>> np.concatenate([a, b])
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that with several (6) arrays but for some reason it added them instead of concatenating. In my actual situation the operation looked like this : ```c = a[:100] + b[:100] + d[:100]```. Where do you think this behaviour might be coming from?

Comment: What are the types of `a`, `b`, and `c`? If those are `numpy.array` then yes they will element-wise add unless you use `concatenate`. If they are plain python lists they will concatenate.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes , they are all numpy. So is concatenate then the only way to go? If have multiple I will inevitable have to loop through them? And in that case, how can I make concatenate be an array of just 1 row instead of 1 column as it is in default?